# Is there a name for this type of popular footer?

Tags: html, widget, footer

Screenshot of a footer:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm unsure if there is a particular name for that kind of footer or if it's a widget for a certain framework. That particular example was taken from buffalonews.com

After I know the name I can refine my searching for implementing it. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the name you're looking for is a [Site Map Footer](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/trends/modern-sitemap-and-footer/). This is common now-a-days to display the contents of the site to the user while also offering crawlers direct links to content pages.

The key here is to display pages that are relevant/important to the user without inundating them so many links they can't figure out where to go.

Answer (score 2):

The part that lists the content of your website is called "sitemap" AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a fairly common set of copywrite notices.

There is no standard widget or way to present this, apart from legal requirements (which may vary depending on where the site operates from).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't think there is actually a name for this king of footer though I agree it is quite common.</strike>

Maybe it is because this "kind" is very subjective and would have to be very specific and most of the times not helpful. (Or maybe because nobody has coined it yet) :)

> Look at [Brad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726083/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-popular-footer/4726123#4726123)

If you have wordpress you could see some [here](http://www.reencoded.com/2009/07/07/20-great-wordpress-footer-designs-for-inspiration/) for inspiration. In wordpress and the popular CMS you can change the footer for many available ones.